# Dúvida sobre o bloco Inicializador

Tags: java, inicialização

Gostaria de saber **por que o código compila mas não executa?**

Segue o código:

```
package exemploinicializador2;

public class ExemploInicializador2 {

   private String nome = "Aurélio";
   private String sobrenome = "Soares";
   private  int idade = 25;
   private  double f = 354.34;

   // Bloco Inicializador
   {
    System.out.println ("Nome: " +nome);
    System.out.println ("Sobrenome: " +sobrenome);
    System.out.println ("Idade: "+idade);
    System.out.println ("F: "+f);
    }
   // Construtor
   public ExemploInicializador2 () {
       System.out.println ("Dentro do Construtor");
   }
}
```

O outro código é:

```
package exemploinicializador2;

public class TesteInicializador2 {
    public static void main (String args []) {
        TesteInicializador2 objeto = new TesteInicializador2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual dos dois não executa? Ambos devem executar, só que no primeiro não possui o main e no segundo não há nada a ser exibido.

Comment: A primeira classe nunca é instanciada. Se não instanciar, não vai exibir nada mesmo.

Comment: A resposta lhe ajudou? Se sim, você pode marcá-la como aceita, clicando no `v` a esquerda da resposta :)

Answer (score 5):

Ambos os códigos compilam e somente o segundo exibe algo. O fato de não exibir nada no terminal não significa que estas ações não ocorreram.

O motivo de não exibir nada da `ExemploInicializador2` é porque em momento algum ela é instanciada. Ora, se não há uma instancia de um objeto desta classe, nada dela será executado.

Tente alterar a segunda classe conforme abaixo:

```
package exemploinicializador2;

public class TesteInicializador2 {
    public static void main (String args []) {
        ExemploInicializador2 objeto = new ExemploInicializador2();
    }
}
```

Neste caso, ambas continuarão sendo compiladas e o trecho da classe `ExemploInicializador2` será executado e exibido, já que estamos instanciando um objeto.

Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/vsLvxV)